# The Case of the Forged Sword

Tags: riddle

Sotheby's New York. Article 522 - An Authentic Ornamental Sword Presented By King George V

Article 522 reads:

"This sword's fascinating history has excited collectors from around the globe. It's find was recorded as one of the most unusual in history. The finder, a Mr. PooPong McPlop, was hurrying to water his pigs and stopped to pick a stray blade of grass that was growing in a nearby meadow. As he stooped down he slipped a disc in his spine, fell into a wheelbarrow which proceeded to deposit him in a nearby well. The rest is history and we now have a sword which we know is authentic due to its very original inscription.

It reads as follows: "*On this day of 19th February 1928 this sword is being presented to Captain Sakhryn-Brown on his remarkable bravery in the Battle of the Somme during WW1. He single-handedly rescued 32 french soldiers and 19 British ones as they were cornered in an apple juice factory. The dear Captain receives this sword posthumously, from His Majesty King George V, after he was taken ill and unfortunately died from cyanide and a sharp writing instrument in 1926*."

The sword is extremely rare due to its sharpness and weight which when one divided by the other the number is exactly pi! It's several rubies are themselves worth slightly more than a crate of Kellog's Cornflakes."

To cut a long story short during the bidding, just as a heavyset gentlemen offered his bid of $34, 971 (thinking of how nice and red it would look, being run through the midriff of his business partner), someone from the back of the room stands up and screams "It's a fake!!!". He, incidentally, is right. How did he know?

Comment: I will object to `french`, in the face of `British` soldiers. ;-)

Comment: @MariusMatutiae well.. that gave my nationality away... :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The crucial term is:

> WW1.  In the year 1928, WW2 was still to come, and there was only a single world war known.

Comment: I remember an Encyclopedia Brown story like this, except it was the First Battle of Bull Run / Manassas